# Woocommerce Product Image Flip on Hover

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress, woocommerce

I am working with a wordpress theme called X theme. My lead dev guy bailed and this function is not working. The purpose of it is to flip to the first image in that products gallery when a mousein/out event occurs. The query is looking for a proceeding post ID which is not there or doesn't meet the criteria for the query. So instead I would like it to simply get the image a better way because this doesn't work consistently.

```
function x_woocommerce_shop_thumbnail() {
              GLOBAL $product;

              $stack            = x_get_stack();
              $stack_thumb      = 'entry-full-' . $stack;
              $stack_shop_thumb = $stack_thumb;
              $id               = get_the_ID();
              $rating           = $product->get_rating_html();
              woocommerce_show_product_sale_flash();
              echo '<div class="entry-featured">';
                echo '<a id="id'.$id.'" value="'.$id.'" href="'.get_the_permalink().'">';
                  echo get_the_post_thumbnail( $id , $stack_shop_thumb ); 
                  global $wpdb;
                  foreach($wpdb->get_results('SELECT ID FROM wp_posts WHERE post_parent = "'.$id.'" AND post_type = "attachment" ORDER BY ID DESC LIMIT 1') as $key => $row){
                    $file = '_wp_attached_file';
                    $childId = $row->ID;
                    global $wpdb;
                    $query = 'SELECT meta_value FROM wp_postmeta WHERE meta_key = "'.$file.'" AND post_id = "'.$childId.'"';
                    $otherImage = $wpdb->get_var($query);
                    if($otherImage != ''){
                        echo '<img id="otherImage" src="/wp-content/uploads/'.$otherImage.'"/>';
                    }
                  }
                  if ( ! empty( $rating ) ) {
                    echo '<div class="star-rating-container aggregate">' . $rating . '</div>';
                  }
                echo '</a>';
              echo "</div>";
             }
```

The java & jQuery for the flip (is running in the footer of theme)

```
    //Product Hover Image Switch

    jQuery(document).ready(function() {

        jQuery('[id^=id]').mouseover(function(){

            if(jQuery(this).children('#otherImage').attr('src') != ''){

                jQuery(this).fadeTo(200, 0, function(){

                    var source = jQuery(this).children('#otherImage').attr('src'),

                        original = jQuery(this).children('.wp-post-image').attr('srcset');

                    jQuery(this).children('.wp-post-image').attr('srcset', source);

                    jQuery(this).children('#otherImage').attr('src', original);

                }).fadeTo(200, 1);

            }

        });

        jQuery('[id^=id]').mouseout(function(){

            if(jQuery(this).children('#otherImage').attr('src') != ''){

                jQuery(this).fadeTo(200, 0, function(){

                    var source = jQuery(this).children('#otherImage').attr('src'),

                        original = jQuery(this).children('.wp-post-image').attr('srcset');

                    jQuery(this).children('.wp-post-image').attr('srcset', source);

                    jQuery(this).children('#otherImage').attr('src', original);

                }).fadeTo(200, 1);
            }
        });
    });
```

Comment: Have you reviewed tutorials such as [this one](https://davidwalsh.name/css-flip) or [this one](http://css3.bradshawenterprises.com/flip/) Those should help with image flipping. Where is `x_woocommerce_shop_thumbnail()` being called/added?

Comment: Hey! thanks for responding. i have the transition working. what going on is the rollover or secondary image (the first image in the product gallery) should display on mouse over but is not. it is defaulting to the primary or featured image instead.

Comment: Ok, still need to know where `x_woocommerce_shop_thumbnail()` is called. And what the desired markup is supposed to be. Right now you are just asking us to debug that block of code and technically that's off topic.

Comment: ok so Ive figure this out. The java/jqery is solid. Just put this into your footer to avoid conflicts with head.

The problem was the query looking for any *. Once you modified the product ID (like change from variable to simple product) the ids would no long be in ascending order with the parent IDs of the images. So The query was re written 1) to be more WP friendly and 2) to look for the most recent child id with that product.  the correct code is below and may be thrown into the Woocommerce Functions to enable the images to flip showing the first gallery image.

Comment: global $wpdb;
  foreach($wpdb->get_results('SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX(meta_value, ",", 1) AS ID FROM wp_postmeta WHERE post_id = "'.$id.'" AND meta_key = "_product_image_gallery"'
) as $key => $row){
    $file = '_wp_attached_file';
    $childId = $row->ID;